# In node.js, is it possible to require('net') without having a net module?

Tags: javascript, node.js

In the "node_modules" folder I don't see a folder called "net", and yet a lot of the code is using `require('net')`. I even did a search for "net" within every folder inside "node_module", but there isn't any.

Comment: It's a part of Node's standard library. You can see other modules that Node comes with [here](https://nodejs.org/api/).

Comment: If you were looking for the source code for the built-in libraries, you can find it here: https://github.com/nodejs/node/tree/master/lib

Comment: Related documentation: [Core Modules](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_core_modules) and [Loading from `node_modules` Folders](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_node_modules_folders) – "*If the module identifier passed to `require()` **is not a native module**, and does not begin with `'/'`, `'../'`, or `'./'`, [...]*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`net`](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html) is built-in package of NodeJS, it is not required to install explicitly. When you use `require('package')`, *package* will be first searched within built-in packages.

To use some other package which doesn't come with NodeJS and is also not installed, it cannot be used.

Taken from [Ben Nadel's blog](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2169-where-does-node-js-and-require-look-for-modules.htm)

1. First, Node.js looks to see if the given module is a **core module** - Node.js comes with many modules compiled directly into the executable binary (ex. http, fs, sys, events, path, etc.). These core modules will always take precedence in the loading algorithm.
2. If the given module is **not a core module**, Node.js will then begin to **search for a directory named, "node_modules"**. It will start in the current directory (relative to the currently-executing Javascript file in Node) and then work its way up the folder hierarchy, checking each level for a node_modules folder.
3. Once Node.js finds the node_modules folder, it will then **attempt to load the given module either as a (.js) Javascript file or as a named sub-directory**. And, if it finds the named sub-directory, it will then attempt to load the file in various ways.
4. If it **still can't find the file in this directory-spidering manner, Node.js will then proceed to look at the directory paths outlined in the "require.paths" array**. The paths values in this array default to the paths defined, in part, by the environmental variable, NODE_PATH; but, they can be updated programmatically within a Node.js application.